# Oracle Problems with Composite Keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

bit confusing question here:
I am trying to create a composite FK from a composite PK. I'll show you my tables in question that I'm having problems with;

```
CREATE TABLE Weapons (
Weapon_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Weapon_Name VARCHAR(30),
Range_In_Meters INT,
Maximum_Number_Of_Uses INT,
Damage_Factor INT,
Cost INT,
primary key(Weapon_ID));

CREATE TABLE WeaponInventory (
Inventory_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
WeaponInventory_ID Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Weapon_ID VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES Weapons(Weapon_ID) NOT NULL,
primary key(Inventory_ID, WeaponInventory_ID));

CREATE TABLE Avatars (
Avatar_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Avatar_Name VARCHAR(30),
AvA_DOB DATE,
Age VARCHAR(30),
Gender VARCHAR(30),
Strength_Indicated INT,
Hoard INT,
Avatar_Level VARCHAR(30),
Skill VARCHAR(30),
Original_Owner VARCHAR(30),
Family_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Species_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Inventory_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Weapon_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Player_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Avatar_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (Inventory_ID, Weapon_ID)
REFERENCES WeaponInventory (Inventory_ID, Weapon_ID));
```

In the table Avatars, I have been trying to create this Foreign key but I'm having no luck. I have errors such as:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

and:

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I just keep getting confused and ending up in the same place! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you planned to reference column `WeaponInventory_ID` (instead of `Weapon_ID`) in table `WeaponInventory`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Inventory_ID, Weapon_ID)
REFERENCES WeaponInventory (Inventory_ID, WeaponInventory_ID) -- see here
```

Note that `Weapon_ID` is not part of the PK in `WeaponInventory`:

```
CREATE TABLE WeaponInventory (
  Inventory_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  WeaponInventory_ID Varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  Weapon_ID VARCHAR(10) REFERENCES Weapons(Weapon_ID) NOT NULL,
  primary key(Inventory_ID, WeaponInventory_ID) -- Weapon_ID is not part of PK
);
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/764e5).

Comment: Ah! I tried to do this again, and I can't believe it worked! 
I had confused myself a bit too much by changing the code in Notepad again and again... So I did this and frustrated myself. But thank-you for pointing this out, hats off to you (: